# How can I make each soldier rotating the other way according to the soldiers indexs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenningScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Animators")]
    public Animator[] animators;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Movement Settings")]
    public Transform target;
    public float movingSpeed = 1f;
    public bool slowDown = false;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Rotation Settings")]
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public DepthOfField dephOfField;
    public float waitingAnimation;
    public float startConversation;

    private Vector3 targetCenter;
    private bool startWaitingAnim = true;
    private bool endRot = false;
    private int medea_m_arrebola_index;
    private int[] soldiers_indexs;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        targetCenter = target.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;

        for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", movingSpeed);

            if(animators[i].name == "medea_m_arrebola")
            {
                medea_m_arrebola_index = i;
            }
            else
            {
                soldiers_indexs[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (dephOfField.dephOfFieldFinished == true)
        {
            PlayConversations.PlaySingleConversation(0);
            dephOfField.dephOfFieldFinished = false;
        }

        float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(animators[medea_m_arrebola_index].transform.position, target.position);

        if (slowDown)
        {
            if (distanceFromTarget < 10)
            {
                float speed = (distanceFromTarget / 10);
                for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
                {
                    animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
                }
            }
        }

        if (distanceFromTarget < 5f)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
            {
                animators[i].SetBool("Idle", true);

                if (startWaitingAnim == true)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(WaitForAnimation());
                    startWaitingAnim = false;
                }
            }

            if (waitinganimation == true)
            {
                animators[medea_m_arrebola_index].SetBool("Magic Pack", true);
                waitinganimation = false;

                PlayConversations.PlaySingleConversation(1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < soldiers_indexs.Length; i++)
            {
                animators[soldiers_indexs[i]].SetBool("Rifle Aiming Idle", true);
                if (!endRot)
                {
                    Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
                    float angleToGoal = Quaternion.Angle(
                            goalRotation,
                            animators[soldiers_indexs[i]].transform.localRotation);
                    float angleThisFrame = Mathf.Min(angleToGoal, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

                    // use axis of Vector3.down to keep angles positive for ease of use
                    animators[0].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angleThisFrame);
                    animators[1].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, angleThisFrame);

                    // We end if we rotated the remaining amount.
                    endRot = (angleThisFrame == angleToGoal);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bool waitinganimation = false;
    IEnumerator WaitForAnimation()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitingAnimation);

        waitinganimation = true;
    }
}
```

Before I used the animators[0] and animators[1] :

```
animators[0].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angleThisFrame);
animators[1].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, angleThisFrame);
```

But now I'm getting the soldiers indexs :

```
soldiers_indexs
```

And I'm using them instead 0 and 1 in the array.
But the problem is how to use the soldiers indexs in this lines ?

```
animators[0].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angleThisFrame);
animators[1].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, angleThisFrame);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a different vector depending on whether the index is even or odd

```
int index = soldiers_indexs[i];
animators[index].transform.Rotate(index % 2 == 0 ? Vector3.up : Vector3.down, angleThisFrame);
```

This `index % 2 == 0` return `true` when the index is even (0, 2, 4, ...). It uses the [modulo operator `%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) yielding the remainder of the integer division.

The ternary operator [?: operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) selects between a true and false case.